# Sentences embedding using word2vec

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, embedding

I'd like to compare the difference among the same word mentioned in different sentences, for example "travel".
What I would like to do is:

- Take the sentences mentioning the term "travel" as plain text;
- In each sentence, replace 'travel' with travel_sent_x.
- Train a word2vec model on these sentences.
- Calculate the distance between travel_sent1, travel_sent2, and other relabelled mentions of "travel"
  So each sentence's "travel" gets its own vector, which is used for comparison.

I know that word2vec requires much more than several sentences to train reliable vectors. The official page recommends datasets including billions of words, but I have not a such number in my dataset(I have thousands of words).

I was trying to test the model with the following few sentences:

```
    Sentences
    Hawaii makes a move to boost domestic travel and support local tourism
    Honolulu makes a move to boost travel and support local tourism
    Hawaii wants tourists to return so much it's offering to pay for half of their travel expenses
```

My approach to build the vectors has been:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

vocab = df['Sentences']))
model = Word2Vec(sentences=vocab, size=100, window=10, min_count=3, workers=4, sg=0)
df['Sentences'].apply(model.vectorize)
```

However I do not know how to visualise the results to see their similarity and get some useful insight.
Any help and advice will be welcome.

Update: I would use Principal Component Analysis algorithm to visualise embeddings in 3-dimensional space. I know how to do for each individual word, but I do not know how to do it in case of sentences.

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly do you want to achieve, and what is the part of word2vec in it. Get similar sentences or  visualize similar words?

Comment: HI igrinis. I would like to visualise similar sentences. The similarity should come from the use of word2vec (or other tool), but preferably based on text semantic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in comparing sentences, Word2Vec is not the best choice. It was shown that using it to create sentence embedding produces inferior results than a dedicated sentence embedding algorithm. If your dataset is not huge, you can't create (train a new) embedding space using your own data. This forces you to use a pre trained embedding for the sentences. Luckily, there are enough of those nowadays. I believe that Universal Sentence Encoder (by Google) will suit your needs best.

Once you get vector representation for you sentences you can go 2 ways:

1. create a matrix of pairwise comparisons and visualize it as a heatmap. This representation is useful when you have some prior knowledge about how close are the sentences and you want to check you hypothesis. You can even [try it online](https://jinglescode.github.io/textual-similarity-universal-sentence-encoder/).
   [image]
2. run t-SNE on the vector representations. This will create a 2D projection of the sentences that will preserve relative distances between them. It presents data much better than PCA. Than you can easily find neighbors of the certain sentence:
   [image]

You can learn more from [this](https://jinglescode.github.io/2020/02/10/build-textual-similarity-analysis-web-app/) and [this](https://medium.com/oneassist-tech-blog/visualizing-context-with-googles-universal-sentence-encoder-and-graphdb-c5f92b2f3db3)

Answer (score 6):

Note that word2vec is not inherently a method for modeling sentences, only words. So there's no single, official way to use word2vec to represent sentences.

Once quick & crude approach is to create a vector for a sentence (or other multi-word text) by averaging all the word-vectors together. It's fast, it's better-than-nothing, and does ok on some simple (broadly-topical) tasks - but isn't going to capture the full meaning of a text very well, especially any meaning which is dependent on grammar, polysemy, or sophisticated contextual hints.

Still, you could use it to get a fixed-size vector per short text, and calculate pairwise similarities/distances between those vectors, and feed the results into dimensionality-reduction algorithms for visualization or other purposes.

Other algorithms actually create vectors for longer texts. A shallow algorithm very closely related to word2vec is 'paragraph vectors', available in Gensim as the `Doc2Vec` class. But it's still not very sophisticated, and still not grammar-aware. A number of deeper-network text models like BERT, ELMo, & others may be possibilities.

Word2vec & related algorithms are very data-hungry: all of their beneficial qualities arise from the tug-of-war between many varied usage examples for the same word. So if you have a toy-sized dataset, you won't get a set of vectors with useful interrelationships.

But also, rare words in your larger dataset won't get good vectors. It is typical in training to discard, as if they weren't even there, words that appear below some `min_count` frequency - because not only would their vectors be poor, from just one or a few idiosyncratic sample uses, but because there are many such underrepresented words in total, keeping them around tends to make *other* word-vectors worse, too. They're noise.

So, your proposed idea of taking *individual* instances of `travel` & replacing them with single-appearance tokens is note very likely to give interesting results. Lowering your `min_count` to 1 will get you vectors for each variant - but they'll be of far worse (& more-random) quality than your other word-vectors, having receiving comparatively little training attention compared to other words, and each being fully influenced by just their few surrounding words (rather than the entire range of all surrounding contexts that could all help contribute to the useful positioning of a unified `travel` token).

(You might be able to offset these problems, a little, by (1) retaining the original version of the sentence, so you still get a `travel` vector; (2) repeating your token-mangled sentences several times, & shuffling them to appear throughout the corpus, to somewhat simulate more real occurrences of your synthetic contexts. But without real variety, most of the problems of such single-context vectors will remain.)

Another possible way to compare `travel_sent_A`, `travel_sent_B`, etc would be to ignore the exact vector for `travel` or `travel_sent_X` entirely, but instead compile a summary vector for the word's surrounding N words. For example if you have 100 examples of the word `travel`, create 100 vectors that are each of the N words *around* travel. These vectors might show some vague clusters/neighborhoods, especially in the case of a word with very-different alternate meanings. (Some research adapting word2vec to account for polysemy uses this sort of `context vector` approach to influence/choose among alternate word-senses.)

You might also find this research on modeling words as drawing from alternate 'atoms' of discourse interesting: [Linear algebraic structure of word meanings](http://www.offconvex.org/2016/07/10/embeddingspolysemy/)

To the extent you have short headline-like texts, and only word-vectors (without the data or algorithms to do deeper modeling), you may also want to look into the "Word Mover's Distance" calculation for comparing texts. Rather than reducing a single text to a single vector, it models it as a "bag of word-vectors". Then, it defines a distance as a cost-to-transform one bag to another bag. (More similar words are easier to transform into each other than less-similar words, so expressions that are very similar, with just a few synonyms replaced, report as quite close.)

It can be quite expensive to calculate on longer texts, but may work well for short phrases and small sets of headlines/tweets/etc. It's available on the Gensim `KeyedVector` classes as [`wmdistance()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.FastTextKeyedVectors.wmdistance). An example of the kinds of correlations it may be useful in discovering is in this article: [Navigating themes in restaurant reviews with Word Mover’s Distance](http://tech.opentable.com/2015/08/11/navigating-themes-in-restaurant-reviews-with-word-movers-distance/)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting take on the word2vec model, You can use T-SNE embeddings of the vectors and reduce the dimensionality to 3 and visualise them using any plotting library such matplotlib or dash. I also find this tools helpful when visualising word embeddings: https://projector.tensorflow.org/

The idea of learning different word embeddings for words in different context is the premise of ELMO(https://allennlp.org/elmo) but you will require a huge training set to train it. Luckily, if your application is not very specific you can use pre-trained models.

Comment: Thanks ATIF ADIB. Unfortunately my training set is not huge. I have hundred of sentences (so thousands of words) and I would like to find a good way to visualise text similarity between them. Sentences in my dataset are very similar to tweets, but actually they are a summary of news (around 200 characters per each). I do not know if there would be a good pre-trained model for that. However, my main difficulties is on how to visualise sentences in a space as array using word2vec (whether possible)

Comment: If your goal is to visualise sentences you can combine the individual word vectors corresponding to the words in the sentence using tf-idf and then visualise them.